# How to debug multithreaded application for Android

Tags: android

how to debug multithreaded application for Android..

I am new to this android platform
I want to debug a native multithreaded application on android. Please let me know the procedure.

Comment: Do this the same way you do any other Java program.

Comment: **Since you are new therefore you must have to read this :http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html**

Answer (score 0):

try Dalvik Debug Service
in the Android SDK go to tools and look for ddms.bat (thats for Windows, not sure about Mac or Linux, but look for ddms)

Comment: I have a native c application which is running on andriod. I want to debug using gdb to debug this application. This is a multi threaded application. I want to debug using using gdb.Is anyone knows how to debug this multithreaded application in andriod using gdb...?

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading, with Handler/AsyncTask ?
Use DDMS or LogCat in Eclipse!